# Child Process (created after forking) when ssh to linux machine from windows getting stuck on windows after sometime

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, openssh, hung

The code snippet shown below works in a way that after forking, the child process ssh from windows to Linux machine, and run script1_bkt.csh on linux machine. And logs are dumped to a windows path ($AngleLogFilePath\Angle_${date}.log === V:\ricky_angle_testing_63.1\depot\vfr\63.10\main\logs\angleLogsrickyPersonal\Angle_${date}.log).

Parent Processes(trialSet.pl and trialSetDepWint.pl) runs in the foreground, and works fine.

V: is network filer or CISF for /dv/lmv/mentor/

**Issue::**

Child process (after the fork process) which ssh onto Linux machine from windows machine and runs script1_bkt.csh get stuck at some point (not everytime).

***Point to Note:*** On a Linux machine(qwelnx45), the PID of script1_bkt.csh doesn't exist after some time which means the process is completed. But, on windows, the PID of ssh.exe (using which script1_bkt.csh is triggered on windows) exists which means on windows, command ($GoToUnix74 cd $ClientAltRoot/lkg ; source script1_bkt.csh ) isn't completed, and got stuck. The script usually takes 3 hrs in completing, but sometimes it never completes as it gets stuck.    ::: This script doesn't get stuck everytime.

Also, one more important point: When child process gets stuck on windows, although script1_bkt.csh is finished on Linux, the log file ( $AngleLogFilePath\Angle_${date}.log) doesn't have all the data which script1_bkt.csh gives i.e. Log file is incomplete (Seems because process got stuck, it stopped writing to log file)

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```
use File::Path qw( make_path );

my $ClientAltRoot           = "/dv/lmv/mentor/ricky_angle_testing_63.1/depot/vfr/63.10/main/";
my $GoToUnix              = "C:\\cygwin\\bin\\ssh.exe qwelnx45";
my $AngleLogFilePath    = "V:\\ricky_angle_testing_63.1\\depot\\vfr\\63.10\\main\\logs\\angleLogsrickyPersonal";
my $date                    = strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", localtime(time));

make_path("$AngleLogFilePath") or warn  "Failed to create dir $AngleLogFilePath";

my $aqpid;
# fork angle process
if ($aqpid = fork()) {
    $SIG{CHLD} = 'DEFAULT';
} elsif (defined ($aqpid)) { 
    sleep 10;

    print "Angle child started\n";
    $angleReturnStatus = system ("$GoToUnix cd $ClientAltRoot/lkg ; source script1_bkt.csh > $AngleLogFilePath\\Angle_${date}.log ");
    $angleFailed += 1 if ($angleReturnStatus > 0);
    exit 0; 
}

print "##### Starting the foreground script ###### \n";
system "$GoToUnix \"cd /home/ricky/; echo abc ;  /home/ricky/trialSet.pl > setTrial_ricky/set_${date}.log\"  ";
print "Ended SetDep\n";     

print "Waiting as child process has not ended";
1 while (wait() != -1);

system ( "perl C:\\ricky\\Testing\\trialSetDepWint.pl ");
print "Demo script ended\n";
```

**Please tell why is the process getting stuck? What could be the possible solution to eliminate this stuck issue?**

-Thanks in Advance.

Comment: IMP:
When the command prompt (program) is hanging, pressing "ENTER" is solving the problem. Means quick mode issue is there i.e. somehow the user is pressing the cursor on the command prompt, and then cmd is going into hang/stuck mode.

So, for the resolution, I turned off the quick mode under the properties of the cmd prompt. But still, the issue is being faced. After turning off the quick mode, selecting anything on cmd mustn't have hung the cmd, but still, cmd is hanging. 

What else can be done for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the issue was due to the following reasons:

1. Quick Mode was ON.  ## **I turned off the quick mode on my system as a solution.**
2. Interruption on the command prompt on which run/script is going on.            ## **Avoid using the machine while the run/script is going on.** Because, when you work on the machine,  willy-nilly you switch command prompts; and due to this switching, your run sometimes gets stuck until you press "ENTER" or any key.

I followed these two methods, and not seeing the issue now.

Thanks.